# Split table into two parts and put them side by side

Tags: output-formatting, table

I have a table that I want to export as an image. The problem is that the table is quite long, so I want to split it and put it side by side (see reference image in case it is not clear. I have case 1 and want case 2). How can I achieve this?

```
gs = ((12 - 3*N1*N2))/(4 + 10*(N1 + N2) - N1*N2*(N1 + N2 + 4) + 
     6*Sqrt[52 - 4*(N1 + N2) + (N1^2 - 10*N1*N2 + N2^2)]);
gd = (-3/2)*((-80 + 2*N1 + 2*N2 + N1^2 + N2^2 + 2*N1*N2 - 
       4*(N1 + N2 + 4)*
        Sqrt[52 - 4*(N1 + N2) + (N1^2 - 10*N1*N2 + N2^2)]))/(464 - 
      56*(N1 + N2) - 16*(N1^2 + N2^2 + N1*N2) + 8*N1*N2*(N1 + N2) + 
      N1*N2*(N1 + N2)^2);
x = gs (N1 + N2 + 1)/(12*Sqrt[N1 + N2]) + gd (N1*N2 + 2)/(12 N1*N2);
nMax = 30; 
TableForm[
 Table[{n, x /. N1 -> n /. N2 -> n, 
   Negative[x /. N1 -> n /. N2 -> n]}, {n, 1, nMax}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {Style["N", Bold], 
    Style["\[ScriptCapitalM]", Bold], 
    Style["\[ScriptCapitalM]<0", Bold]}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

gs = ((12 - 3*N1*N2))/
   (4 + 10*(N1 + N2) - N1*N2*(N1 + N2 + 4) +
     6*Sqrt[52 - 4*(N1 + N2) + (N1^2 - 10*N1*N2 + N2^2)]);
gd = (-3/2)*
   ((-80 + 2*N1 + 2*N2 + N1^2 + N2^2 + 2*N1*N2 -
       4*(N1 + N2 + 4)*
        Sqrt[52 - 4*(N1 + N2) + (N1^2 - 10*N1*N2 + N2^2)]))/
    (464 - 56*(N1 + N2) - 16*(N1^2 + N2^2 + N1*N2) + 
      8*N1*N2*(N1 + N2) +
      N1*N2*(N1 + N2)^2);
x = gs (N1 + N2 + 1)/(12*Sqrt[N1 + N2]) + gd (N1*N2 + 2)/(12 N1*N2);
nMax = 30;

nCol = 2;

Prepend[
  Table[n = (c - 1) nMax/nCol + r;
   Sequence @@ {n, x /. N1 -> n /. N2 -> n, 
     Negative[x /. N1 -> n /. N2 -> n]},
   {r, 1, nMax/nCol}, {c, 1, nCol}],
  ConstantArray[
    Style[#, Bold] & /@ {"N", "ℳ", 
      "ℳ<0"}, nCol] // Flatten] //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]